# Replace escaped single quote with single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, escaping

I have a service returning results as JSON string with escaped single quote. Ex: `O\\\'Neill`. Now, when displaying I need to unescape it to say `O'Neill`. I have tried replacing the string but doesn't work and it throws a script error - *Expected ")"* when I tried to assign the text (HTML) to a DIV.

Comment: Posting some code would help - you probably just typoed somewhere in it...

Comment: Fix the service or fix the data. Either it is returning "O\\'Neill" and you would be better off having text data rather than that or you have "O\'Neill" which is forbidden in JSON. Don't try to clean this up client side.

Comment: Why is the single quote escaped at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than escape it server side, why not replace it with the HTML entity `&#39;`?

Comment: Because, generally speaking, it is better to have plain text than HTML if you don't need any of the semantics that HTML expresses. It is easier to convert from text to whatever you need then it is to convert from HTML to whatever you need.

Comment: Although I agree with the overall approach. I tend to think that a question tagged with Javascript, jQuery and JSON will end up being rendered in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just practicing my psychic powers here...but is your code trying to replace `"\"` with `""`?  If so, remember, you'll need to escape the backslash (as it's the escape char in Javascript).  Try replacing `"\\"` instead.

As mentioned up in the comments, though, the best fix would be to the service.  There should be no need for `\'` in JSON (and in fact, it's technically not even valid JSON), as the values should be double-quoted (making it unnecessary to escape a single quote).

Comment: You've most likely identified the source of his *Expected ")"* error. Now...  what am I thinking?

Comment: Dunno.  The first thought in my head is that PHP's magic quotes are evil.  I'm probably still in Dave's problem though.  :)